# Extracting parts of array repeatedly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array:

```
[a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2, a3, b3, etc]
```

How do I select every b and c without a for loop? Can I use slicing or anything else?

The resulting array should look like this:

```
[b1, c1, b2, c2, b3, c3, etc]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use masking. Provided your input array has always a length in a multiple of 4, you can create a mask of pattern `False, True, True, False`. I am taking an input of strings for example.

```
arr = np.array(['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3'], dtype='str')
mask = [False, True, True, False]*int(len(arr)/4)

print (arr[mask])
# array(['b1', 'c1', 'b2', 'c2', 'b3', 'c3'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the data you want with [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

data = np.array(['a0', 'b0', 'c0', 'd0', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'])
s = data.strides[0]
# No data is copied
data2 = as_strided(data[1:], shape=(data.size // 4, 2), strides=(4 * s, s), writeable=False)
print(data2)
# [['b0' 'c0']
#  ['b1' 'c1']
#  ['b2' 'c2']]
data3 = data2.ravel()  # This causes a copy
print(data3)
#['b0' 'c0' 'b1' 'c1' 'b2' 'c2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `filter` and `map`

```
l = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'a3', 'b3']
newlist = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] % 4 == 1 or x[0] % 4 == 2, enumerate(l)))
newlist = list(map(lambda x: x[1], newlist))
print(newlist)
```

if they are string, `filter` is enough

```
l = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'a3', 'b3']
newlist = list(filter(lambda x: 'b' in x or 'c'in x, l))
print(newlist)
```